# Vectorize loop with if else conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, optimization, vectorization

The dataframe I have contains the events of users on my mobile app and I want to create sessions for my users. What I am doing is if the user does any action on my app for 90 minutes I am tagging all the events for that user to the hour he first came to my platform.

The issue is that the loop is taking a long time to run as my dataframe contains some 1.5 millions rows. Is there a better way to do this by vectorizing? I am using R.

```
for(a in 1:nrow(sample)){
  print(a)
  if(sample[a,]$rankj == 1){
    user = sample[a,]$email
    fixday = sample[a,]$dt_timestamp
    fixtime = sample[a,]$date_time
    fixhour = hour(fixtime)
    sample[a,]$session_hour = fixhour
    sample[a,]$session_day = fixday
    
    lasteventday = sample[a,]$dt_timestamp
    lasteventtime = sample[a,]$date_time
    
  } else if(difftime(sample[a,]$date_time, fixtime, units = "mins") <= 90 | difftime(sample[a,]$date_time, lasteventtime, units = "mins") < 5 ){
    sample[a,]$session_hour = fixhour
    sample[a,]$session_day = fixday
    
    lasteventday = sample[a,]$dt_timestamp
    lasteventtime = sample[a,]$date_time
    
  } else if(difftime(sample[a,]$date_time, fixtime, units = "mins") > 90){
    fixday = sample[a,]$dt_timestamp
    fixtime = sample[a,]$date_time
    fixhour = hour(fixtime)
    sample[a,]$session_hour = fixhour
    sample[a,]$session_day = fixday
    
    lasteventday = sample[a,]$dt_timestamp
    lasteventtime = sample[a,]$date_time
  }
  
}
```

[This is a sample of the dataframe I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssHsJ.png)

[This is the sample with the new column that I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDBaH.png)

Comment: You can rewrite it with `fcase` in `data.table` or `case_when` in `dplyr`.

Comment: Please provide a small data example of `sample`, e.g. `dput(head(sample,10))` and your expected result.

Comment: Hey, I have attached a sample of my input and output. Can you check that?

Comment: Hey, picture is not  a good way because its  inconvient to be reproduced. Still please try to use `dput(head(sample,10))`, that's not complicated.

Comment: You loop is a little strange,  in all branch of if-else, `lasteventday = sample[a,]$dt_timestamp
    lasteventtime = sample[a,]$date_time` are all satisfied.

Comment: `fixhour` , `fixday` , `fixtime` and `lasteventtime` are not defined in the second if-else branch.

Comment: We can put the ```lasteventday = sample[a,]$dt_timestamp     lasteventtime = sample[a,]$date_time``` outside the if...else. The ```fixhour``` , ```fixday``` , ```fixtime``` and ```lasteventtime``` need not be defined in second if-else because I do not want to change those values in that condition

Comment: I means that if the first branch of if-else is not satisfied initially the second branch will don't know the value of `fixhour , fixday , fixtime, lasteventtime`.

Comment: That case will hold true for the first time

Comment: Ok. Another question, your provided picture seems different with the description of your code,  `dt_timestamp,rankj` are not shown. Do you only want to create a column `hour`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is extremely complicated and unreadable. See how it can be done smarter and faster.

Unfortunately, you did not give us the data so I have to generate it myself.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(utils)

n=10

dt_tm = c(seq(ymd_hms("2021-01-01 00:00:01"), ymd_hms("2021-01-01 01:15:45"), 62),
           seq(ymd_hms("2021-01-01 02:10:15"), ymd_hms("2021-01-01 02:18:08"), 40),
           seq(ymd_hms("2021-01-01 07:55:55"), ymd_hms("2021-01-01 09:02:07"), 126),
           seq(ymd_hms("2021-01-01 11:22:09"), ymd_hms("2021-01-01 12:12:43"), 30),
           seq(ymd_hms("2021-01-01 16:12:49"), ymd_hms("2021-01-01 18:33:35"), 130))


sample = tibble(
  event_name = sample(paste("event", 1:10), length(dt_tm), replace = TRUE),
  date_time  = dt_tm,
  user_id = 394839
)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 285 x 3
   event_name date_time           user_id
   <chr>      <dttm>                <dbl>
 1 event 8    2021-01-01 00:00:01  394839
 2 event 8    2021-01-01 00:01:03  394839
 3 event 6    2021-01-01 00:02:05  394839
 4 event 3    2021-01-01 00:03:07  394839
 5 event 7    2021-01-01 00:04:09  394839
 6 event 7    2021-01-01 00:05:11  394839
 7 event 1    2021-01-01 00:06:13  394839
 8 event 1    2021-01-01 00:07:15  394839
 9 event 10   2021-01-01 00:08:17  394839
10 event 3    2021-01-01 00:09:19  394839
# ... with 275 more rows
```

As you can see we have a table with 5 sessions of different duration.
Now we have to write two clever functions that will do what you expect.

```
timeRound = 90
sesionID = function(x) cumsum(ifelse((x-lag(x, default = x[1]-6*60))>5*60,1,0))
sesionHour = function(x) hour(x[1]) +
  plyr::round_any(as.integer(x-x[1])/60,timeRound)/timeRound
sesion_Hour = function(data) data %>% 
  mutate(sesionHour = sesionHour(.$date_time))
```

He should take a look at them very carefully. The function `sesionID` numbers the consecutive sessions, i.e. the periods of time between which the intervals between events were shorter than 5 minutes.
The `sesionHour` function returns the time rounded to `timeRound`. Why did you choose 90 minutes? I have no idea but sure you have your reasons.
The function `sesion_Hour` will help us when mutating on grouped data.
Now let's see how it works.

```
sample = sample %>% mutate(sesionID = sesionID(date_time)) %>%
  group_by(sesionID) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~sesion_Hour(.x))) %>%
  unnest(data)
```

output `sample %>% ungroup() %>% slice_head(n=10)`

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   sesionID event_name date_time           user_id sesionHour
      <dbl> <chr>      <dttm>                <dbl>      <dbl>
 1        1 event 9    2021-01-01 00:00:01  394839          0
 2        1 event 9    2021-01-01 00:01:03  394839          0
 3        1 event 1    2021-01-01 00:02:05  394839          0
 4        1 event 1    2021-01-01 00:03:07  394839          0
 5        1 event 4    2021-01-01 00:04:09  394839          0
 6        1 event 5    2021-01-01 00:05:11  394839          0
 7        1 event 3    2021-01-01 00:06:13  394839          0
 8        1 event 9    2021-01-01 00:07:15  394839          0
 9        1 event 2    2021-01-01 00:08:17  394839          0
10        1 event 1    2021-01-01 00:09:19  394839          0
```

output `sample %>% ungroup() %>% slice_tail(n=10)`

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   sesionID event_name date_time           user_id sesionHour
      <dbl> <chr>      <dttm>                <dbl>      <dbl>
 1        5 event 8    2021-01-01 18:11:59  394839         17
 2        5 event 6    2021-01-01 18:14:09  394839         17
 3        5 event 8    2021-01-01 18:16:19  394839         17
 4        5 event 7    2021-01-01 18:18:29  394839         17
 5        5 event 4    2021-01-01 18:20:39  394839         17
 6        5 event 8    2021-01-01 18:22:49  394839         17
 7        5 event 10   2021-01-01 18:24:59  394839         17
 8        5 event 3    2021-01-01 18:27:09  394839         17
 9        5 event 9    2021-01-01 18:29:19  394839         18
10        5 event 7    2021-01-01 18:31:29  394839         18
```

As you can see, everything works great. Well, it's time to test on a larger data set. Let's prepare a table with 1.7 million rows.

```
ndays = 1000
nusers = 6
sample2 = tibble(
  date_time  = rep(rep(dt_tm, each=ndays)+
    rep(seq(ddays(1), ddays(ndays), ddays(1)), each=length(dt_tm)), each=nusers),
  event_name = sample(paste("event", 1:10), length(date_time), replace = TRUE),
  user_id = rep(394839:(394839+(nusers-1)), each=length(date_time)/nusers)
)
```

Let's measure how long it will take us to mutate our table.

```
start_time =Sys.time()
sample2 = sample2 %>% mutate(sesionID = sesionID(date_time)) %>%
  group_by(user_id, sesionID) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~sesion_Hour(.x))) %>%
  unnest(data)
Sys.time()-start_time
```

For me it took 3.5 seconds. Can you wait that long?